# Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [English Language Learners Stack Exchange](http://ell.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why aren't currency names capitalized?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17517/why-arent-currency-names-capitalized)

**Net Score: 15** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Question about "might like" vs. "would like"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16865/question-about-might-like-vs-would-like)

**Net Score: 14** (Excellent: 15, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is this phrase grammatically correct: "Look, there is a little me and little all of uses!"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17919/is-this-phrase-grammatically-correct-look-there-is-a-little-me-and-little-all)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 12, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [What does “A man passed him, and a man and a woman, talking” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17986/what-does-a-man-passed-him-and-a-man-and-a-woman-talking-mean)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What does this "electric" mean and function here?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17552/what-does-this-electric-mean-and-function-here)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [No more than [a time expression here]](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16615/no-more-than-a-time-expression-here)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Hold back + preposition](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/16543/hold-back-preposition)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 11, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- ["All items have weight one" or "All items have weights one"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17146/all-items-have-weight-one-or-all-items-have-weights-one)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What does “but” mean?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17678/what-does-but-mean)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [Can I start a sentence with "Besides" just followed by a comma?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/17412/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-besides-just-followed-by-a-comma)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 12, Needs Improvement: 5)

---